# Mongodb document validation

Tags: mongodb

I need your help on mongodb document validation. I am trying to create the mongodb document structure below:

```
db.createCollection("People2", {
  validator: {
    $and: [
      {
        Identity: {
            Number: { 
                $type: "string", 
                $exists: true  
            },
            Type: { 
               $type: "string", 
               $exists: true 
            }
        }
      },
      {
        "lastName": { 
          $type: "string", 
          $exists: true
        }
      },
      {
        "email": {
          $type: "string",
          $exists: true,
        }
      },
      {
        UserVerification: { $in: [ "Rejected", "Validated" ] }
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

Below command to test document insertion:

```
db.People2.insert(
        {
          IdentityCard: { 
             Number: "#1234",
             Type: "typeA"
          },
          lastName: "toto", 
          email: "toto@mydom.com", 
          UserVerification: "Validated"
        }
);
```

But a get this error:

```
WriteResult({
        "nInserted" : 0,
        "writeError" : {
                "code" : 121,
                "errmsg" : "Document failed validation"
        }
})
```

I think The problem come from the object "Identity" validation declaration which is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and your statement is using IdentityCard but not Identity.

```
db.createCollection("People2", {
  validator: {
    $and: [
      {
        "IdentityCard.Number": { 
                $type: "string", 
                $exists: true  
            },
         "IdentityCard.Type": { 
               $type: "string", 
               $exists: true 
            }
      },
      {
        "lastName": { 
          $type: "string", 
          $exists: true
        }
      },
      {
        "email": {
          $type: "string",
          $exists: true,
        }
      },
      {
        UserVerification: { $in: [ "Rejected", "Validated" ] }
      }
    ]
  }
})
```